# Alternating Harmonic series in java

Tags: java, math

**I can't figure out how to solve this problem, and i have been staring at it for hours. I need to write a code that follows 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 + ... 1/n, but all i can figure out how to do is 1 + 1/2 +1/3 +1/4 + 1/n. The code i have so far is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("enter");
    int c = input.nextInt();

    for (double i = 1; i <= c; i++) {

        if (i % 2 ==0) {
            a-= (1/i);
        }
        if (i % 2 !=0){
            a+=(1/i);
        }
    System.out.print(a + " ");
}
```

The problem is:

Write a program that reads a sequence of positive integer values ending with the sentinal value 0. For each value (call it n), compute and print
1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 + ... 1/n
Each result (one per input value) should be on the same line, separated by a ", " (comma space). However, if the value of n at some point is less than the previously read value of n, then end the current line of results (i.e., print a new line), then print the word "reset" on the next line, then print the next set of results on the next line.
The end of the output should contain the words "end of results" on a separate line (use println).**

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! I recommend you take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Have you made an attempt?

Comment: Yes, I can get the normal harmonic of 1+(1/2)+(1/3)... just not alternating.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
   double a = 0;
  

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.print("enter");
  int c = input.nextInt();
  
//while (a != 0){
 for (double i = 1; i <= c; i++) a+= (1/i);
 
   System.out.print(a + " ");

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and edit your post with the code that you have currently so its easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For alternating sings I would use miltiplication to (-1)^(i), or in this case (-1)^(i-1).
What for printing every number up to the result, it happens because you print it inside the loop, so naturally it prints eevry time. You should print it after the loop ends.

Comment: Thank you very much! The last thing I need to do is if a number is entered that is smaller than the first number entered, the program prints "Reset". I don't know if I assign another variable to what the last input was.

Comment: Do you need to comare to the very first input, or to the previous one? For the former try something like `boolean isFirst = true; int first; int c = input.nextInt();  if(isFirst){first = c; isFirst=false}  else if(c<first){System.out.println("Reset");}`  For the latter `int prev = 0;  int c = input.nextInt();  if(c<prev){System.out.println("Reset");}  prev = c;`

Comment: Just the previous one. So if I entered 10 20 30 5 the program would keep going until it got to 5. Then it would print "Reset" on a new line and then the calculation on another line

Answer (score 1):

You have a good question, we just need to improve the quality of your post a bit. Stack Overflow is a site for helping you solve your coding issues, but we won't write them 100% for you. Providing us with your code or anything else you've attempted is always helpful.

You mentioned that you know how to get the normal harmonic, but not the alternating signs. Start by looking for a pattern. Given n, we need to print n numbers, but only n - 1 operators. This means we have a fencepost problem. In this case, I think it's fairly obvious that we always need to print 1 first. Then each subsequent print is an operator and a fraction.

- When n = 2, we use subtraction before the fraction.
- When n = 3, we use addition before the fraction.
- When n = 4, we use subtraction before the fraction.
- When n = 5, we use addition before the fraction.

What is the pattern here? I'll give you a hint: even numbers are preceded by subtraction and odd numbers are preceded by addition...

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking i need two if statements. One for evens and one for odds.

Comment: Sure thing, don't forget to post your code as well next time you post a question.

Comment: I came up with this but it still does not work. for (double i = 1; i <= c; i++){
  
 if (c%2==0){
  a+= (1/i);
 }
  if (c%2!=0){
   a-=(1/i);
  }
 
   System.out.print(a + " ");

Comment: I'm having trouble reading the code you posted. Could you try to format this a bit more? The indentation is all over the place. Stack Overflow uses 4 spaces to detect code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just read about how to fix the formatting. When i run the program, it prints the correct number at the end. But it also prints every number up to N. How would i fix that?              Example: i enter 5                                                        it prints 1.0 1.00.5 0.50.8333333333333333 0.83333333333333330.5833333333333333 0.58333333333333330.7833333333333332 0.7833333333333332

Comment: So in this example, you just want to print 0.7833333333333332, is that correct? Why not just change your print statement to `if (i == c) { System.out.print(a + " "); }`

Comment: Thanks! The only thing left that i cant figure out is how to compare the new input to the previous input

Comment: You probably just need a while loop. Something like `while (condition == true) { repeat method call. Store value in some data structure }` Is that what you mean?

Comment: I wasn't sure if i could do that in a while loop. So lets say i input 4, it runs through the program, then i enter 3. It will print "reset" and then the calculation. So i was thinking an if statement comparing the new input to the previous input. I just don't know how.

Comment: Oh sure. At the very end of the method when you print the result, why not store it in a data structure, say an ArrayList or something. Then when you input 3, you could store that value in the List as well and access both of them whenever you want.